# GitKraken somehow blocks .tmp pack-files renaming

Tags: git, garbage-collection, file-permissions, gitkraken

Faced an issue while trying to run `git pull` via internal GitKraken terminal: git runs `git gc` first because of the large amount of loose files, but it throws a message:

```
Rename from '.git/objects/pack/.tmp-12756-pack-43ce9a6189aabeb8f1ef4126bc54123a482da265.pack' to '.git/objects/pack/pack-43ce9a6189aabeb8f1ef4126bc54123a482da265.pack' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

Nothing helps except aborting this operation which leads to an error message

```
fatal: renaming '.git/objects/pack/.tmp-12756-pack-43ce9a6189aabeb8f1ef4126bc54123a482da265.pack' failed: Permission denied
```

Running this command in an external terminal fails with the same error, everything works fine only when GitKraken is closed. How to fix it?

Comment: Is this on Windows? Windows (as an OS) offers programs the ability to create this sort of problem; usually the only way around it is to avoid running the offending program.

Comment: @torek yes, on Windows. Thought there should be a way to avoid this problem

Comment: Unfortunately, WIndows offers "mandatory locking" on files, where if some process opens a handle to a file, that file can no longer be renamed or deleted. It also offers a non-locking open, but the program has to be written to use it (and handle the error that occurs if the file is removed while it's open) and people tend to use the lazy "prevent me from getting whacked" variety of "open a file" here.

Comment: If you can get the source to GitKraken and modify it, you can fix it up to use the non-locking variety of open. This won't necessarily be easy (if it were easy, someone probably would have done it already...).